# Avoiding column name redundancy accessing SQL databases?

Tags: java, c++, sql, c, language-agnostic

I'm working on a program using a SQL database (I use SQLite). What my program does is the following:

1. Creates the tables in the database if they don't exist (on startup)
2. Executes SQL queries (SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE) - decided by the user from the interface

What I saw doing this is that there is **a lot** of redundancy. I give the name of the columns when I create the tables and also when I update or insert information in the table.

```
CREATE TABLE USERS (
USER_ID,
NAME,
ADDRESS);

UPDATE USERS (
NAME='John Smith'
WHERE USER_ID='1'
);
```

This can be frustrating when dealing with more than 3 or 4 tables and mistakes can happen if I misspell the name of a column.

I would like to know if there's a designer capable of creating/generating these SQL queries by just giving some specifications about the table's description.

Thank you for any suggestion,

Iulian

PS: The code is written in Java but I must be able also to access the code from a C/C++ command line program.

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of solution you're imagining.  You need to specify all the column-names when you create the table.  You need to specify specific column-names when you create a query (otherwise, how could you specify what you want the query condition to be?).  I suppose you could store all the names in some sort of map, but then your queries would end up like `"UPDATE USERS (" + name[0] + " WHERE " + name[1] + "='1');`.  Is the structure of these tables dynamic?  (i.e. can it vary at run-time, or is it known at compile-time?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the basic idea behind an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) such as Ruby on Rails' [ActiveRecord](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/), [hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/), and similar technologies. Basically you set the configuration for a table - or use a standard naming convention - and the framework will generate your CRUD (`INSERT` / `SELECT` / `UPDATE` / `DELETE`) queries for you.